# Android contacts aggregation process

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm unable to find detailed information about the aggregation process in Android's contacts. I'm aware of the `ContactsContract.Contacts` -> `ContactsContract.RawContacts` -> `ContactsContract.Data` structure (as described on http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html), and that a `Contact` consists of `Raw Contacts`, which are grouped together through one `Contact_ID`.

What I specifically want to know is: under what circumstances are Raw Contacts grouped into one Contact?

I found [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21709/how-does-android-contact-linking-work) question and answer - specifically the last option:

> At least one of the two raw contacts is missing the name altogether and they are sharing a phone number, an email address or a nickname (for example, `Bob Parr [incredible@android.com] = incredible@android.com`).

I tried this out, however, it doesn't seem to work. I want to know if I can add a Raw Contact to the local contacts and ***set only the `ACCOUNT_TYPE`, `ACCOUNT_NAME` and phone or emailaddress***, and if this will be automatically aggregrated with a raw contact for whom this phone number or emailaddress already exists. So for example:

(`ContactsContract.Contacts.`)`_ID` (Similar to `ContactsContract.RawContacts.Contact_ID`): 1188300 consists of:

- Raw Contact ID 20905
  `MIMETYPE = \email_v2`
  `ACCOUNT_TYPE = com.google`
  `NAME = Example Test`
  `EMAIL = test@gmail.com`
- Raw Contact ID 20897
  `MIMETYPE = \phone_v2`
  `ACCOUNT_TYPE = com.google`
  `NAME = Example Test`
  `EMAIL = 123456`

After adding the following:

- Raw Contact
  `MIMETYPE = \email_v2`
  `ACCOUNT_TYPE = com.exampleApp` 
  `EMAIL = test@gmail.com`

***will this result into:***
(`ContactsContract.Contacts.`)`_ID`: 1188300 consisting of:

- Raw Contact ID 20905
  `MIMETYPE = \email_v2`
  `ACCOUNT_TYPE = com.google`
  `NAME = Example Test`
  `EMAIL = test@gmail.com`
- Raw Contact ID 20897
  `MIMETYPE = \phone_v2`
  `ACCOUNT_TYPE = com.google`
  `NAME = Example Test`
  `EMAIL = 123456`
- Raw Contact ID 20899 (or whatever number)
  `MIMETYPE = \email_v2`
  `ACCOUNT_TYPE = com.exampleApp`
  `NAME = Example Test`
  `EMAIL = test@gmail.com`

Answer (score 1):

The contacts aggregation is handled by the [ContactAggregator2.java](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_providers_contactsprovider/blob/master/src/com/android/providers/contacts/aggregation/ContactAggregator2.java)

What is does is match every raw contact with other raw contacts, the aggregations is done based on a score generated by [RawContactMatcher](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_providers_contactsprovider/blob/master/src/com/android/providers/contacts/aggregation/util/RawContactMatcher.java)

The file contains a little explanation, but you can check the score assigned for different parameters and also the matching scores (EXACT, CONSERVATIVE and APPROXIMATE).

Example for Name-

```
/**
 * Name matching scores: a matrix by name type vs. candidate lookup type.
 * For example, if the name type is "full name" while we are looking for a
 * "full name", the score may be 99. If we are looking for a "nickname" but
 * find "first name", the score may be 50 (see specific scores defined
 * below.)
 * <p>
 * For approximate matching, we have a range of scores, let's say 40-70.  Depending one how
 * similar the two strings are, the score will be somewhere between 40 and 70, with the exact
 * match producing the score of 70.  The score may also be 0 if the similarity (distance)
 * between the strings is below the threshold.
 * <p>
 * We use a string matching algorithm, which is particularly suited for
 * name matching. See {@link NameDistance}.
 */
```

If you want two contacts to be aggregated(Joined) just add an entry in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions.html with type as TYPE_KEEP_TOGETHER

Comment: AggregationExceptions: You can only update this one, you can't add new entries per documintation