# How to control android contact aggregation

Tags: android, outlook, android-contacts

I have an app that exports contacts. Similar contacts get aggregated by an internal scoring mechanism, see [Android contacts aggregation process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33150632/android-contacts-aggregation-process)

My issue is that the same contacts exported with Outlook for Android get a different aggregation.

To test this i have created one contact (Identicus) with name, given name, work phone and email 5 times. It gets aggregated for both apps.

I have created another two contacts (Hans Test and Hans Othertest) with the same given name and work phone, but different names.
When i export it the two contacts get aggregated, when Outlook exports it they are **not** aggregated.

With ContactsContract.RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE_DISABLED i can disable aggregation for all my contacts - but i want the identical contacts to be aggregated.

I checked https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.AggregationSuggestions to see if i could identify the contacts that were about to be aggregated and un-aggregate them by using an AggregationException, but the data seems to be not useful.

Does anybody have an idea why the aggregation works differently for Outlook and my app?
Or a hint how i could control this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

AggregationExceptions is indeed the key here.

If you know the RawContact IDs of the contacts in question you can tell Android to aggregate them, or un-aggregate them by adding an AggregationException.

So if the RawContacts have ids 111 & 222 -

```
ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(AggregationExceptions.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValue(AggregationExceptions.TYPE, AggregationExceptions.TYPE_KEEP_SEPARATE)
            .withValue(AggregationExceptions.RAW_CONTACT_ID1, 111)
            .withValue(AggregationExceptions.RAW_CONTACT_ID2, 222)
            .build()
```

will keep those raws separated, and -

```
ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(AggregationExceptions.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValue(AggregationExceptions.TYPE, AggregationExceptions.TYPE_KEEP_TOGETHER)
            .withValue(AggregationExceptions.RAW_CONTACT_ID1, 111)
            .withValue(AggregationExceptions.RAW_CONTACT_ID2, 222)
            .build()
```

will keep those raws aggregated.

you'll of course need to apply the operations, via something like:

```
context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, operations);
```

Comment: I am pretty sure Outlook does not use any AggregationExceptions, at least there is no trace in their apk (taking a peek with jadx).

As there are potentially thousands of contacts i would have to re-implement the whole Android aggregation framework - so i am looking for an easier solution.

Comment: `Outlook does not use any AggregationExceptions` that's probably true, contacts sync-adapters usually don't handle aggregation on their own, but rely on the system built-in aggregation logic to merge their contacts with other sync-providers' contacts.

Comment: apps that DO have AggregationException in their code are contact apps, like google's "Contacts" app, or Contacts+, these apps offer the user to manually split / join contacts, and when that happens the app will use AggEx for that, also it is usually accompanied by surfacing duplicate suggestions to the user

Comment: @marmor can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/q/63970269/5457916 ?